# How do I add a calendar in SharePoint 2016?

Tags: sharepoint-online

that multiple persons can edit?  I can only find instructions for 2013, and those include a ribbon, which I can't even find in 2016.

I'm not a coder :/, and our coders are not available.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you have permissions to create new lists and you are not working in a Publishing site:

- Click the Settings (gear) icon at the top left of the page.
- Click "Add an App".
- Find the Calendar icon and create a Calendar list.

If you are working in a Publishing site:

- Click the Settings (gear) icon at the top left of the page.
- Click Site Settings (You may need to be a Site Owner)
- Find and click Site Features
- Click the Enable button for "Team Collaboration Lists".
- Click "Add an App".
- Find the Calendar icon and create a Calendar list.

Notes:

- All users with edit/contribute permissions to the site will be able to add/edit items in the calendar.
- You can break inheritance on the calendar if you would like to setup custom permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Where do you cannot add a calendar in SharePoint 2016? Please offer a screenshot.

You said that "I can only find instructions for 2013, and those include a ribbon". Where is the ribbon you are referring to?

It's possible you created your site with a Publishing Portal template and there are some features not turned on by default.

1. Go to the "Site Settings"
2. Go to "Manage Site Features"
3. Check "Team Collaboration Lists" feature is activated or not. If not, activate the feature.

http://sharepointwriting.blogspot.com/2011/10/missing-calendar-list-in-sharepoint.html

To add an calendar list, navigate to the site->add an app:

[image]

Then search for calendar, you can create an calendar list:

[image]

Comment: Is there anything update?